# MSAL python AADSTS900971 No reply address provided

Tags: python, docker, flask, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api

I am running the following sample python application inside a Linux docker container.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp
Docker is started using CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"] command.
While connecting with http://publicip:5000 I am able to see the signing page and it displays **AADSTS900971: No reply address provided** after authenticating successfully.

I am completely unaware of accessing this docker application from a public IP using MSAL. Please help.

I am able to test this application without any issues from Windows machine using http://localhost:5000
Reply URL: http://localhost:5000/getAToken

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to include the redirect URL in your registered application on your B2C tenant. You could use the http://publicip:5000 URL as well. Maybe you have another redirect URL for confirmed logins, that would work as well.

[Screenshot URL Redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOuSI.png)